# how to indicate on post listing title if user already liked this post

Tags: php

I am using this [post like system](https://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/wordpress-post-like-system/) in my WordPress theme. i want to indicate any type of like icon or something on post title on all listing page, so that logged in user can know without open that he is already liked this post.

for example please take a look this sample :

[image]

can someone help me with a solution?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code for that like system, you should be able to find out if the user has liked the post like this:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $likes = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_liked_posts', true );

    if ( is_array( $likes ) && in_array( get_the_ID(), $likes ) ) {
        echo '<span class="liked">Liked</span>';
    }
}
```

That will echo a `<span>` with the class `liked` if the user has liked the post. That code will need to go in the template where you want the "Liked" badge to appear.

Comment: thank you @Jacob Peattie for comments, but sorry to say its not working. no output result

Comment: can someone help me with a solution?

Comment: any solution or guide line please ?